# Convert milliseconds to Date format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I set a Date string to milliseconds to start from midnight like:

```
var date = new Date("2017-12-14").setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)
```

Now the **date = 1513209600000; i.e., Thu Dec 14 2017 00:00:00**. This is exactly how I want to start my date from midnight or start of the day, i.e., midnight.

But when I'm trying to convert this timestamp to again in Date object, it is not retaining the hour format, like:

```
var dateObj = new Date(date); // Thu Dec 14 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I want this **dateObj** to have the date and time to start from midnight. Can anyone please suggest what exactly I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are having problems with Timezones: Notice how it's 5:30 of GMT+5:30...

Comment: `setUTCHours` returns *The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the updated date.* Your millisecond value is already offset'd by `5:30` hours as per your system's timezone.

Comment: @gurvinder372— "*Your millisecond value is already offset'd…*" no it isn't, the time value is always UTC so it's not offset. It's the local value returned by *toString* that is offset (based on the host timezone).

Comment: Note that `new Date("2017-12-14")` will be parsed as UTC and the time will be set to 00:00:00UTC by defualt, there is no need to zero the UTC hours.

Answer (score 3):

The date object is retaining its value, what you see is your browser's representation of that date in the local time zone. Try `dateObj.toUTCString()` to read the original value.

Answer (score 0):

I think use should change setUTCHours to setHours

```
var date = new Date("2017-12-14").setHours(0,0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per EMCA-262, a date string in ISO 8601 format like "2017-12-14" will be parsed by the built-in parser as UTC (contrary to ISO 8601) and the time will be set to 00:00:00 UTC so there is not need to zero the hours.

So in:

```
var date = new Date("2017-12-14").setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)
```

the *setUTCHours* call is redundant.

Since you are +05:30, then for the period from local midnight to 05:30, the UTC date will be the previous day.

If you want to parse "2017-12-14" as a local date with the time set to 00:00:00, then you can either:

1. Parse the string yourself and set it to local midnight on the correct date
2. Parse the string as UTC and adjust for the host timezone offset

For case 1:

```js
function parseISOLocal(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2]);
}
 
 var s = "2017-12-14";
 
 console.log(parseISOLocal(s).toString());
```

For case 2:

```js
var s = "2017-12-14";
// Parsed as UTC
var d = new Date(s);
// Adjust for host timezone
d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset());
// Show local date
console.log(d.toString());
```